# What is CDbl doing?

Tags: vb.net, parsing, casting, type-conversion

I had until recently been under the impression that the `CDbl(x)` operation in VB.NET was essentially a cast (i.e., the VB equivalent of `(double)x` in C#); but a recent discovery has revealed that this is not the case.

If I have this string:

```
Dim s As String = "12345.12345-"
```

And I do this:

```
Dim d As Double = CDbl(s)
```

`d` will be set to the value `-12345.12345`! Now, don't get me wrong, this is kind of convenient in my particular scenario; but I have to admit I'm confused as to *why* this works. In particular, I'm confused because:

- `Double.Parse` does not work with the above input.
- `Double.TryParse` does not work.
- `Convert.ToDouble` does not work.

How is `CDbl` so clever?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It uses Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToDouble().  That function contains a Select statement on the object's GetTypeCode() return value so it can use a custom converter based on the type of the argument.  The string converter considers the possibility that the string might contain a currency value and does some processing on the string to deal with that.  One allowed format for currency values is a trailing negative sign.

This is not particularly cheap.  The quickest way to achieve the same conversion is:

```
Dim s As String = "12345.12345-"
Dim d As Double = Double.Parse(s, Globalization.NumberStyles.Any)
```

Comment: Thanks for the in depth answer. As a VB6 programmer that converted to  .NET, I've always tried to do things "the .NET way" instead of using the old vb function way. For example: .substring instead of Left, Mid, Right, .ToLower instead of LCase etc.

Answer (score 1):

That's always been the behavior of `CDbl()` in Visual Basic 4/5/6 and is currently specific to VB.NET (it's inline, not part of the framework), so it's probably just been kept for people moving from earlier versions.

(Much like weirdness in pre-.NET Visual Basic due to features bought over from [QBasic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QBasic).)

Answer (score 0):

If you go into Regional Options in Control Panel, there's a setting that let's you put the minus sign after, instead of before, numbers.

I'm not sure what system uses a minus sign after numbers, but it seems CDbl is programmed to accept both. Be liberal in what you accept, and all that.

Regional Options also has a setting for negative numbers where they are in brackets. Does that work? -- `CDbl("(12345.12345)")`